# Module javafx.controls not found

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx

My previous javafx projects are working fine but not able to create any new project as I get the above error.

See below

[image]

My VM args are:

```
--module-path C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

Though I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 but the above VM args worked fine until now. However if I create a new Class in my existig JavaFx project then it works. But not in new project.

Thanks in advance for any help. :-)

Comment: The VM args look a bit Windowish to me. Since when do you have a C drive in Linux?

Comment: @mipa: I already mentioned that in my post. Please re-read. Is there some other args I can pass to the VM?

Comment: This "C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11\lib" should probably be something like "/Users/<user>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11/lib" but check precisely on your system. Note the '/' instead of '\'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it made me realise that this arg is actually not correct so I just kept the part "--add-modules=javafx.controls". The javafx programs seem to work again. Thnaks again. :-)